# How to create Multiple Criteria VBA Macro

Tags: excel

I am a new programmer when it comes to VBA and I am writing a code that scans multiple Criteria and then copy and pastes to another sheet. I have 2 Sheets right now Sheet1 and Sheet2, I will first need to scan J9 on Sheet1 and then lookup Sheet2 for Sheet1’s J9, afterwards I will pull everything with J9 in it from Sheet2 to Sheet1 with it starting at a specific Row, I’ve tried doing AutoFilter but as I am rarely new I believe that my code should be obsolete, please go easy on me. Many Thanks in advance! PS(I am using VBA 2013)

Sub tgr()

```
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim acrit() As String

Set wsData = Sheets("MaterialReport")    'Copying FROM this worksheet (it contains your data)
Set wsDest = Sheets("TIMINGBELTWPULLEY")        'Copying TO this worksheet (it is your destination)

'Populate your array of values to filter for
ReDim acrit(1 To 2)
acrit(1) = "TIMING"

acrit(2) = "PULLEY"



With wsData.Range("C1", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter 1, aFruit, xlFilterValues   'Filter using the array, this avoids having to do a loop

    'Copy the filtered data (except the header row) and paste it as values
    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Copy
    wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B29").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False     'Remove the CutCopy border
    .AutoFilter     'Remove the filter
End With
```

This is my code that I’m working with, I’ve pulled it from a training site and edited it to my needs